# How to enable display iframe pointing to the site without an SSL certificate on a Web site that uses the certificate?

Tags: iframe, https, html-editor

I have a question that goes some way to enable display iframe pointing to the site without an SSL certificate on a Web site that uses the certificate?

**1. First method:** When I put iframe to WP Html post editor:

```
< iframe src="http://.." width="100%" height="700"></iframe>
```

It's not working, iframe is showed like 404 error.

**2. Second method:** I made custom file scrapedcontent.php and uploaded it to root of web.

File scrapedcontent.php code:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://..');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Then I call this file trough iframe from WP post:

```
< iframe src="/scrapedcontent.php" width="100%" height="700"></iframe>
```

This works, but not at all, CSS styles not loaded etc..

Any idea how to properly iframe http site to https site are much appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to achieve something that is being blocked by most browsers. https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/

Comment: ..true, because I need solution for this, any workaround, I heard about some proxy trick. anyone know?